# AngularJS Animation Tabs Won't Fade In

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to get AngularJS to fade in a tab pane when you select. I have it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamclayd/m9g7d4q5/)

I have the following CSS to animate it with:

```
    .tab-pane.active-add {
        transition: opacity 10s;
        opacity: 0
    }

    .tab-pane.active-add.active-add-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

As you can see when you go to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamclayd/m9g7d4q5/) it does not fade in when you change a tab.

Comment: Nowhere in your HTML are you setting the `active-add` or `active-add-active` class. This means this part of CSS is never valid for your page. Neither the first nor the second selector. Adapt your HTML so you actually use the classes you define in CSS (or the other way round).

Comment: `active-add` and `active-add-active` get added to the class list when active gets added. If you look at the dev tools you can actually see them there for 10 seconds after you click on a tab.

Answer (score 0):

use a .css like this:

```
.tab-pane.active:not(.show) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.tab-pane.active{
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

Then declare a new variable

```
  $scope.active_show=0;
```

Now use ng-class to add the two classes

```
<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active:  active === $index,
                                 show:  active_show === $index}" 
      ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        {{tab.content}}
</div>
```

And change your function like

```
  $scope.setActive = function(index) {
    $scope.active = index;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $scope.active_show=index;
      $scope.$apply();
    })
  }
```

The idea is that your div, when active has first a class `.active` and in a new cycle -it's the function of `setTimeOut`- the class is `.active.show`

your [fork jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8kcjw9h/)

NOTE: I use the use of .show/not(.show) because it's the way, e.g. bootstrap, use

NOTE2: I imagine you're work in an old project, AngularJs is a bit old and soon you Sooner rather than later should change to Angular